# Horizontal Boxes that Stack on Mobile - Centered with Image, Title Text and Detail Text

Tags: html, css

Having trouble conceptualizing how to go about making this set of boxes. They need to be horizontal and centered, but stack on a smaller screen size. Also need to center the image and two types of text. Appreciate your thoughts!

[image]

What I have so far:
Need to start with a main container and hold all 4 boxes inside of it. Not sure how to get the horizontal display or the stacking feature on smaller screens. Also unsure how to center the content inside of each box - not sure if I should use static or dynamic formatting inside the boxes.

Comment: Have you written any code to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using flex and media queries if you don't want to go down the bootstrap (or other grid layout) route.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <h1>Title Text</h1>
    <div>detailed text that explains what the title means</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <h1>Title Text</h1>
    <div>detailed text that explains what the title means</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <h1>Title Text</h1>
    <div>detailed text that explains what the title means</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <h1>Title Text</h1>
    <div>detailed text that explains what the title means</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .box {
    width: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvMPQe

Answer (score 0):

Check out [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/).  It is a responsive plugin used in many websites including Twitter.  Highly recommend and great for designing multiplatform websites.